# ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 972 ORA-06512: at line 54

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I made a anonymous procedure to download an image from BLOB field(IMAGE) but I'm getting an error, which is triggered at line 57: DBMS_LOB.READ(lob_loc => v_lob_loc, amount => v_amount, offset => v_offset, buffer => v_buffer);

```
 DECLARE
    cursor c is 
    select id,REG_CODE  from STUDENT where DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(IMAGE)>0;
          v_lob_loc      BLOB;
        v_buffer       RAW(32767);
        v_buffer_size  BINARY_INTEGER;
        v_amount       BINARY_INTEGER;
        v_offset       NUMBER(38) := 1;
        v_chunksize    INTEGER;
        v_out_file     UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;


BEGIN

for i in c
loop

 SELECT  IMAGE
INTO    v_lob_loc
FROM   STUDENT
WHERE   id =i.id;

-- +-------------------------------------------------------------+
-- | FIND OUT THE CHUNKSIZE FOR THIS LOB COLUMN                  |
-- +-------------------------------------------------------------+
v_chunksize := DBMS_LOB.GETCHUNKSIZE(v_lob_loc);

IF (v_chunksize < 32767) THEN
    v_buffer_size := v_chunksize;
ELSE
    v_buffer_size := 32767;
END IF;

v_amount := v_buffer_size;


DBMS_LOB.OPEN(v_lob_loc, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);

-- +-------------------------------------------------------------+
-- | WRITE CONTENTS OF THE LOB TO A FILE                         |
-- +-------------------------------------------------------------+
v_out_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(
    location      => 'ALL_IMG_DIR', 
    filename      => I.REG_CODE||'.JPG', 
    open_mode     => 'wb',
    max_linesize  => 32767);

WHILE v_amount >= v_buffer_size
LOOP

 DBMS_LOB.READ(           lob_loc    => v_lob_loc,           amount     => v_amount,          offset     => v_offset,          buffer     => v_buffer);

  v_offset := v_offset + v_amount;

  UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW (
      file      => v_out_file,
      buffer    => v_buffer,
      autoflush => true);

  UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(file => v_out_file);


END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(file => v_out_file);

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_out_file);

-- +-------------------------------------------------------------+
-- | CLOSING THE LOB IS MANDATORY IF YOU HAVE OPENED IT          |
-- +-------------------------------------------------------------+
DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(v_lob_loc);

UPDATE STUDENT SET IMAGE =EMPTY_BLOB() WHERE ID=I.ID;

end loop;


END;
```

Comment: You have a ORA-01403 which is a NO_DATA_FOUND. Is the `SELECT  IMAGE...` statement fetching any rows?

Comment: yeah, it facing data and i have tested the size of v_lob_loc

Answer (score 1):

This link to the oracle documentation explains how to handle this sort of exception - 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_lob.htm
You can find under the headline "BFILE-Specific Rules and Limitations
", they explain this exception comes from reaching the end of the file, and how to wrap you're loop in an exception handler to catch this error and handle it gracefully.

Comment: If you've found this answer helpful, please mark it as the correct answer.